# Performance of sort command in unix

Tags: linux, unix, sorting, pipe

I am writing a custom apache log parser for my company and I noticed a performance issue that I can't explain. I have a text file log.txt with size 1.2GB.

The command: sort log.txt is up to 3 sec slower than the command: cat log.txt | sort

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Is one call taking longer than the other because the log file has grown in the interim?

Comment: No. I work on a local copy of the file.

Comment: Is it because on the second try (the cat|sort) log.txt was read from cache, not disk, so you saved on disk access, not actual sorting?  please run your sort through strace -C and see how much time goes toward disk access.  Or just put the file on a ramdisk and run your experiments there.

Comment: If it's 1.2 GB it might be worth it to try this:
LC_ALL=C sort log.txt
LC_COLLATE=C might also help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat file | sort` is a [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

> The purpose of cat is to concatenate
>   (or "catenate") files. If it's only
>   one file, concatenating it with
>   nothing at all is a waste of time, and
>   costs you a process.

It shouldn't take longer. Are you sure your timings are right?

Please post the output of:

```
time sort file
```

and

```
time cat file | sort
```

You need to run the commands a few times and get the average.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thanx! I was only checking a single output of the time command. When ran 5 times and taking the average the version without cat seems to be approximately 2 secs faster! Thanx a lot for the link also!

Comment: @user744734: before taking the average, you should discard outlier values, in this case, at least the run that warms the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about the performance of `sort` instead you should change your logging:

- Eliminate unnecessarily verbose output to your log.
- **Periodically roll the log (based on either date or size).**
- ...fix the errors outputting to the log. ;)

Also, are you sure cat is reading the entire file? It may have a read buffer etc.